# Access to Global::Hashtable from function in Powershell

Tags: powershell, function, hash, global

I write Poweshell Cmdlets and get error over error

```
#cut
$global:Vertraege = @{}

function xy
{
 #local access is working
   $local_Vertraege = @{}

   $local_Vertraege += ( @{ i=1; ag="AG1"; we="WE1" } )
   $local_Vertraege += ( @{ i=2; ag="AG2"; we="WE2" } )
   $local_Vertraege += ( @{ i=3; ag="AG2"; we="WE3" } )
#global access is not working, throws exception, why?
   $global:Vertraege += ( @{ i=4; ag="AG4"; we="WE4" } )
}
#/cut
```

Working with the `$local_Vertraege` is doing fine.
`$local_Vertraege` gets populated with 3 Example sets
But I need to access `$global:Vertraege`
how can i get data set 4 into global Hashtable?

I get this error (in German):

```
Der Zuweisungsausdruck ist ungültig. Die Eingabe für einen Zuweisungsoperator muss ein Objekt sein, das Zuweisungen akzeptieren kann (z. B. eine Variable oder Eigenschaft).
```

How can I access/change a global Hashtable from inside a function?

Comment: You have duplicate keys `i`, `ag` and `we`. What exactly is the end goal here? What should `$local_Vertraege` and `$global:Vertraege` look like after invoking `xy`?

Comment: Perhaps you actually wanted an array of hashtables ? Like `$local_Vertraege = @()` and `$global:Vertraege = @()`

Comment: I started with my needed global Hashtable and and want to collect there all data.
function xy is a recursion.
I do not understand ojw to acces the $global:Vertraege and I wanted to show an example, that when accessing the $local:vertraege there is no problem.

Comment: just inside the function I might get duplicate key problems. that's correct, but not my problem.
but when i want to access the global:vertraege from inside function xy nothing is working anymore.
and this is the big question for me

Comment: the big goal is  just to populate $global:vertraege from inside a function.
the local implementation is just an example, that the syntax is working.

Comment: "that's correct, but not my problem" - it _is_ your problem. Depending on the `$ErrorActionPreference` set, the `$global:Vertraege +=` line might not be reached if the previous statements fail

Comment: I added some comments to explain my problem hopefully more understandable

Comment: You can solve this by removing the failing code above it (or by introducing some error handling)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax used to write data back to the global `Vertraege` variable *is correct* - you can observe this by removing the failing code above it:

```
PS ~> $global:Vertraege = @{}
PS ~> function xy { $global:Vertraege += ( @{ i=4; ag="AG4"; we="WE4" } ) }
PS ~> xy
PS ~> $Vertraege

Name                           Value
----                           -----
we                             WE4
ag                             AG4
i                              4
```

Comment: OK, I am coding for severeal years now, but what I did is my best fault ever.
AND I WON'T DO IT AGAIN.
I had a '+' sign in the first column an I didn' see it.
Ok, the week was a bit harder, BUT NOT THIS!!!
Thx to you all for trying to open my eyes ans a special hug to Mathias.
Your post pushed me again into my Source, which I already had examined 1000 times...